# How do you programmatically check if there are updates to your installed programs with winget?

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, cmd.exe, winget

I've spent a ridiculous amount of time trying to make use of `winget`.

If I simply run `winget upgrade`, or `winget upgrade <package>` for each program I care about, it not only checks if there is an update, but **actually updates**, which frequently means it will get perpetually stuck waiting for a prompt of some kind. Not all installers just run smoothly and make the update. I know this from experience.

Since actually updating programs through `winget` requires me to sit there and actively deal with it (the flag to "skip prompts" does not work), I want to only check *whether* there are updates, so that I can script logic to determine if I should notify myself about having to run the `winget upgrade` commands.

But if I do `winget list`, while it does list the information I want (program names, installed version, available version), it does this as a for-human text output, which is obnoxious to try to parse for my script. It does not support outputting as JSON. (And I'm in cmd.exe context, from necessity -- *not* PowerShell.)

However, there is a feature called "export", which ostensibly does exactly what I want: outputs a JSON file with the program names and... no versions. However, it has a secret flag called `--include-versions`. **However**:

```
winget export -o "tmp.txt" --include-versions
```

... only includes the **currently installed version** -- not the "available version" column! This makes it impossible to use this JSON output to determine whether any given program has an available update!

What on Earth were they thinking when they designed this system? What could they be intending that I'm supposed to do to learn this info? I actually have to figure out a way to regexp the for-human text output after all? It feels so wrong and so stupid, especially when they have a literal "export to JSON" feature which **avoids the crucial information of the "available version"**.

As usual: I must be missing something.

Comment: Have you tried WingetUI, a graphical interface for Winget? https://www.marticliment.com/wingetui/ This might be easier to use to *review* items without immediately *updating*.

Comment: @Destroy666 The whole point was to script this. As such, a GUI program is the opposite of what I need.

Comment: I didn't recommend a GUI

Comment: @Destroy666 "v1.4.10173". Please see my comment on the below answer; I was wrong about a small detail but it doesn't change what I basically ask about.

Comment: “What on Earth were they thinking when they designed this system? What could they be intending that I'm supposed to do to learn this info?” - **You really should remove these unanswerable questions from your question.**

Comment: Also, if you feel the output formats should be more parsing-friendly then winget is on GitHub: https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli Or you could ask a more specific question about your batch parsing attempts of it instead.

Comment: @Destroy666 Github doesn't allow registration. It's been impossible for me to register (and keep for more than a few seconds) an account there for many years now.

Answer (score 2):

Unless your `winget` is bugged or something (it's not for me on latest `1.4.10173` version):

`winget upgrade` without any switches by default just lists packages that could be updated.

`winget upgrade --all` is the command to actually upgrade everything.

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/package-manager/winget/upgrade#using-upgrade) also confirms this behavior.

> To identify which apps are in need of an update, simply use **upgrade** without any arguments to show all available upgrades.

For a single package you can also use `winget list "packagename"` or
`winget list package.id`.

All of the mentioned commands list `Name`, `Id`, `Version`, `Available`, `Source` columns. The data is separated with varying number of spaces, so advanced parding with batch will be required if you have to use that.

Comment: Well, it does it in the same "for-human" text output. Not easily parseable. My point stands.

Comment: 1. I asked the question but you seem to not read it. 2. I explicitly mention that I'm NOT in PowerShell context.

Comment: I missed that, my bad (even though not sure why you wouldn't be able to use PS, what about other installable CLI tools?), but it's still possible to parse with batch, not as easily, but you won't find anything better.

Comment: Well, there's also `winget list [packagename]` for a single package, but it also doesn't look like perfect material to parse. I'll add info about it to the answer though

Comment: `winget list [packagename]` just gives the same output as `winget list`, so I don't know what you mean by that. And Powershell has massive issues which are too complex to mention here.

Answer (score 0):

By the way, I wrote and published a module to help using winget. WingetPosh.
[See here](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/wingetposh/1.0.1)

[GitHub Site for details](https://github.com/Yves848/WingetPosh)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I won’t downvote this answer but just point out the author clearly indicate they were using a command prompt out of necessity instead of PowerShell. If this answer explained how to use their module and script the authors solution I would have upvoted it.